# How to make my terminal look like this

Tags: linux, tmux

I ran across this the other day and was instantly amazed.

[image]

He says he uses a custom Vim colorscheme (easy) and dwm with tmux.

I've downloaded tmux and I'm having some issues with it (my CTRL-b hotkey wont work), but I'm confused at how to start designing something similar to what he has done.

My idea is to get my terminal to look like this, then remove KDE from my laptop so that all my computer is is this awesome thing.

How should I go about starting modeling something like this? In the picture, what does tmux handle and what does dwm handle? Speaking from someone who has never used any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the tmux configuration (which covers some of the colour theming which bawkstoo incorrectly stated that tmux couldn't do) in that screenshot in Jason Ryan's [mercurial repository](http://beta.intuxication.org/jasonwryan/archer/file/tip/.tmux/conf). I'm sure if you dig into other parts of the jasonwryan's repo you should be able to more of less have the same setup.

The info on setting up tmux's statusbar is in a [blog post](http://jasonwryan.com/post/6381226449/tmux-status) by jasonwryan as well

Answer (score 2):

tmux is for managing multiple terminal sessions within a single terminal (just like GNU Screen), so it would not play directly into colors/themes etc, it does however show some info in the footer section of that terminal (information about the other terminal buffers, etc).  dwm is a very light window manager, you can modify the colors/themes of your windows within this (that flat/boring look of the whole window that you are after would be done here, as well as the header area of that terminal).

You would have to boot into dwm instead of KDE to begin building and testing a look like this.

Comment: Ohhh! I didn't know dwm was a replacement for KDE or Gnome and such. Thanks for the info. One more thing, how would one edit the small footer section in tmux?

Comment: You can customize almost everything about tmux in your `~/.tmux.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Not rep-tastic enough to comment yet, but if you arrived here because you searched, **my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>  binding doesn't work** then you should check your `~/.tmux.conf` for the line,

`bind C-a   send-prefix`

which is a common tmux practice which re-binds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> as your prefix. (Shortcut: Just try using `C-a` instead; it might be that someone already changed it on your config.)